# how do I get zend framework to say 'hello world' in a browser?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I finished some of the steps in http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html and got it to work to the point where if I type 'localhost' in my browser, I arrive at the Zend server test page.

I have experience using xampp and php (decided recently to start using a framework for some of my client works) and in xampp i create all of my test pages under the folder 'htdocs' and simply type 'localhost/mysites/test.php'. I have no idea how to do that.

Before I get into actually using all of the MVC stuff the Zend framework is about, I have to know where to save all of my php files and for now I just want to simply display 'hello world' via zend so I know where to save files and what address to type in the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is not very clear. Anyway, I assume that you've created in the right way your project. To print 'hello world' in your browser, do this little change:

In the **IndexController.php**, inside the indexAction() method write:

```
$this->view->String = 'hello world';
```

Now go in the **index.phtml** file under view/scripts/index and write (better if you delete all the lines you see in it):

```
<?php echo $this->String; ?>
```

Now, typing in the address bar of your browser localhost, you should be able to see 'hello world'. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Please check [Zend Framework Installation or Hello world Zend Framework](http://kirensiv.blogspot.in/2013/01/this-tutorial-explains-how-you-can.html#comment-form). This guide us how to install Zend Frame Work along with proper screen shots attached in it.